# Output an array.Find the largest element of the array. C#

Tags: c#

A 2D array of integers B(M, N) is set using a random number sensor. Display the array. Find the largest element of the array. Print its indexes.

I do not know what to do with m, n and how to find max

```
namespace Program

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int m,n; Random rnd = new Random();
        m = 4; n = 4; int max;
        int[,] m1 = new int[m,n];

        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(int j =0;j<n;j++){
                m1[i,j] = rnd.Next(100);
                Console.Write(m1[i,j] + "\t");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Another comment and this one is ment to be constructive. Even though you can do multiple statements on a single line, don't do it! Code is suposed to be readable.

Comment: I'm not joking. I pay for the university, but my teacher does not teach us, but throws only tasks. I've been working on this task for 2 hours. I won't write any more. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shouldn't have done this, but I figured it may be an actual question of someone who actually tried.

```
namespace Program

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            
            var m = 4;
            var n = 4; 
            
            int max = 0;  // you don't need to say zero but it makes it more clear
            
            int[,] m1 = new int[m, n];

            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    m1[i, j] = rnd.Next(100);
                    Console.Write(m1[i, j] + "\t");
                    
                    if (m1[i, j] > max)
                        max = m1[i, j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I could of done a better job, but I wanted it to be similar enough so they could potentially learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int m,n; Random rnd = new Random();
    m = rnd.Next(10); n = rnd.Next(10); 
    int[,] m1 = new int[m,n];

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j =0;j<n;j++){
            m1[i,j] = rnd.Next(100);
            Console.Write(m1[i,j] + "\t");
        }
    }
    int maks = m1[0,0];
    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (m1[i, j] > maks)
                    maks = m1[i, j];
            }
        }
    Console.WriteLine(maks);
```

Comment: maybe it will be useful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).